Intermittent CSRF token mismatch errors on Django login
I am experiencing intermittent CSRF token mismatch errors in my Django application, specifically on the login, sign-up, and admin login pages.
Environment:
Django version: 4.2 - 4.2.10
Middleware configuration:
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'impersonate.middleware.ImpersonateMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_browser_reload.middleware.BrowserReloadMiddleware',
]

Issue Details:

The CSRF failure occurs randomly but only on the login, sign up, and admin login pages, all of which use Django's default forms and CSRF management.
The HTML form causing the issue uses standard Django templating for CSRF tokens:

<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <!-- form fields -->
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>


I have been monitoring the issue for a while by using the "csrf_failure" function where I log all the information I have. There seems to be a mismatch between the cookies.get('csrftoken', '') and request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken', ''). But don't understand why.

Any ideas or suggestions for additional debugging that might help identify the root cause?
Thank you in advance

Have you implemented these settings in settings.py ? CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

Nope. I'm not cross-sharing resources, except for the custom domain, everything is on the same domain. Still, do you suspect it could be it? I wanted to avoid the security concern but can easily check it out with some logs

Yeah I had to use it even for sharing resources across my own server not sure what the reasoning was but in general need it for sharing resources on a live domain web server. Might be worth trying.

Well, I tried implementing those settings, but it still happens.
